# keras .h5 file + other data use

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

Thanks to all Stackoverflow users.

I have a question about a .h5 file.
For example, data [A, B, C, D, E, Train] data.

Train with [Train + A] data.
Binary classifications with tags Good and Bad respectively.

Save the verified .h5 file.

And can you derive meaningful predictions later from the .h5 file? (Model.predict method)

In other words, does the prediction value of [.h5 (model) + B] data make sense?

B differs only in data, but the classification table is the same.[Good,Bad]

If this is not possible, do we have to retrain to determine the B data set?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save a trained model, and load it to use for predictions:

```
from keras.models import load_model

model.save("./model1.h5") # SAVE
model = load_model("./model1.h5") # LOAD (already compiled)
```

This will load the model architecture, optimizer state, and weights. You can then use the model to run inference: `model.predict(input_data)`

To save only the *weights* of the model, see below; when loading, be sure to *compile* the model after, and that the model has the same layer weights. [Further reading](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model)

```
model.save_weights("./model1_weights.h5") # SAVE
model.load_weights("./model1_weights.h5") # LOAD
model.compile(...) # COMPILE
```

Comment: should the input data be pre-processed?

Comment: @powerfulfrog That's for you to decide; most of the time, the 'test' data is preprocessed the same was as the train data, for consistency. Unless you preprocess data differently at each train iteration, it's best to preprocess ahead of time, save, and load train/predict-ready data.